# Unexpected time spent in new and delete operation

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory

I was wondering about which way is better for delivering some data between functions, by copy or passing pointer ( new and delete ). So, I tested that time spent in new and delete operation and copy. Copy time increase linearly, which is expected.

But, I got Strange time from new and delete. At 500KB It took more time than 510KB and those after 500KB. Further more, after 500KB It showed the bigger the memory , the less the time it take.

(Is it because that Windows keep memory in "big" chunk. So that when allocating  memory more than 500KB, it was easier for Windows? Then, why 500KB?)

So, Copy is better when size of data below 500K, otherwise use pointer?

Dose anyone have some idea about this?

below were time i got. It was take average after 10000 operations.

(env: win7, vs2010)

## new and delete:

size: 10K NewDleteAverageTime:0.012293ms
size: 20K NewDleteAverageTime:0.027168ms
size: 30K NewDleteAverageTime:0.0502781ms
size: 40K NewDleteAverageTime:0.0739503ms
...
size: 210K NewDleteAverageTime:0.116843ms
size: 220K NewDleteAverageTime:0.117263ms
size: 230K NewDleteAverageTime:0.0960635ms
...
size: 430K NewDleteAverageTime:0.165539ms
size: 440K NewDleteAverageTime:0.162156ms
size: 450K NewDleteAverageTime:0.126388ms
size: 460K NewDleteAverageTime:0.168734ms
size: 470K NewDleteAverageTime:0.196589ms
size: 480K NewDleteAverageTime:0.25601ms
**size: 490K NewDleteAverageTime:0.25485ms

size: 500K NewDleteAverageTime:0.264911ms

size: 510K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00591305ms

size: 520K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00230184ms**
size: 530K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00215912ms
size: 540K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00219284ms
...
size: 980K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00241015ms
size: 990K NewDleteAverageTime:0.00244989ms
size: 1000K NewDleteAverageTime:0.0024912ms
size: 10M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00311146ms
size: 20M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00297647ms
size: 30M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00302636ms
size: 40M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00310456ms
size: 50M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00311733ms
size: 60M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00312078ms
size: 70M NewDleteAverageTime:0.0032505ms
size: 80M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00322513ms
size: 90M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00328945ms
size: 100M NewDleteAverageTime:0.00330236ms

## copy: linearly

size: 110K CopyAverageTime:0.0128748ms
...
size: 480K CopyAverageTime:0.0286189ms
size: 490K CopyAverageTime:0.0261801ms
size: 500K CopyAverageTime:0.0295913ms
size: 510K CopyAverageTime:0.0308001ms
size: 520K CopyAverageTime:0.0308093ms
size: 530K CopyAverageTime:0.0306727ms
...
size: 1010K CopyAverageTime:0.0804052ms
...
size: 1810K CopyAverageTime:0.183536ms
...
size: 3710K CopyAverageTime:0.400298ms
...
size: 10M CopyAverageTime:1.80764ms
...
size: 60M CopyAverageTime:10.7776ms

## here are my code

```
void NewDeleteTime( Unit U )
{
    ofstream out("NewDeleteTime.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    string strUnit = Unit_M == U ? "M":"K";
    int UnitSize = Unit_M == U ? M1 :K1;

    const int interval = 10;
    const int MaxSize = 1001;
    const int repeat = 1000;

    vector<char*> vecData;
    vecData.reserve(10);

    TimerCounter tmr;

    int max = Unit_M == U ? 101 : 1001;

    for (int size = 10; size < max; size += interval)
    {
        // setSrcData( size * M1);

        tmr.Start();

        for ( int times = 0; times < repeat; ++ times )
        {
            // new
            for ( int i =0; i < 10; ++i )
            {
                char* pD = new char[size * UnitSize];
                vecData.push_back( pD );
            }


            // delete
            for ( int i =0; i < vecData.size(); ++i )
            {
                delete[] vecData[i];
            }

            vecData.clear();
        }

        tmr.Stop();

        cout<<"size: "<<size<<strUnit<<" NewDleteAverageTime:"<< tmr.dbTime * 1000 / repeat / 10 <<"ms"<<endl;
        out<<"size: "<<size<<strUnit<<" NewDleteAverageTime:"<< tmr.dbTime * 1000 / repeat / 10 <<"ms"<<endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> (Is it because that Windows keep memory in "big" chunk. So that when allocating memory more than 500KB, it was easier for Windows? Then, why 500KB?)

500K is implementation dependent. It can be different for another system or compiler.

> So, Copy is better when size of data below 500K, otherwise use pointer?

Rule of thumb - don't do anything you don't have to.
Even if copy and allocation are relatively cheap, it is better to use pointers for any big enough data (bigger than 16-32 bytes, your mileage can vary).